# C# Tcplistener server

Tags: c#, sockets, stream, byte, tcplistener

I have a TCPListener (server side). 
When the data is retrieved, it has all the streams concatenated into one string. I need to use them separately. I read somewhere on the internet that I need to send the length of each stream and handle it on the server side. I did so, but when I retrieve the stream, the length is not numeric, rather it has the values "0?".

I am using the following code to retrieve the streams:

```
bytes = new byte[listener.ReceiveBufferSize + 1];
int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
```

This code will get me all the streams concatenated into the "data" field. So I need to be able to retrieve each stream separately. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're saying if 5 connections are made, they are being bunched into 1 string?

Comment: @BugFinder No, its one connection, but the client can send bulk data. 
Therefore, they all are retrieved into 1 string. 
I have no problem in the case of 1 stream.

Comment: So, the client makes multiple connections, or is it sending multiple chunks of data? it cant send sockets :P

Comment: @BugFinder multiple chunks of data.

Comment: Then show how you're sending the data .. your chunks of data will merge if you dont have any obvious control on them

Comment: @BugFinder I am sending them through IBM AS400 machine (RPGLE language) and not .NET
the retrieval is using .net. Plus I cannot change the sending of the data, I have no access on the code. I need to fix the retrieval.

Comment: Actually worryingly i speak RPG :P (sssh dont tell anyone) .. however, if its just spitting out data, without any form of terminator or control info, it will arrive your end as just random chunks...

Comment: They are not random. The order is correct. But they are all concatenated and I need to use them separately.

Comment: they are in effect random chunks, eg if stirngs of 10 then 20, then 30 were sent with no terminators you'd see 102030 ... so it feels "random" especially if you have no predetermined size.. eg its not padded with nulls or whatever

Comment: it also may not  help that you use data += ..

Comment: _"Help me implement a message framing protocol"_ (which is what this question is implicitly asking) is way too broad of a question. Search the web for "C# message framing protocol tcp length prefix".

Comment: That's right. How can I solve it?

Comment: @BugFinder What can I use instead of += ? I am new to .NET so I need some help here.

Comment: Do you know what += does?